# how to convert NSData from zipFile to char *

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion, nsdata

In general, we use "[data bytes]" to convert nsdata to (char * or bytes),
but when the NSData object is from a zipFile, [data bytes], it will only left "PK\03\04".

I want to get the original chars, is there any ways to do it?
thanks

Comment: It makes no sense to convert a binary file to `char *`. Arbitrary binary data is not a string.

Comment: HexData (`(NS)Data`) are not always "transformable" into `(NS)String`. It doesn't make sense. Ask you this: "What is the representation of the `Data` of a .png image? Not all hex have a String/char equivalent (and useful).